# Bootstrap sidebar navigation resizing issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some issues with my Bootstrap 3.3.6 sidebar navigation.

**Problem #1 -**
When in mobile view the content does not want to follow padding-top: 70px to be positioned lower under the fixed-top navigation bar. This occurs when the sidebar (left hand side) turns into standard Bootstrap top navigation.

**Problem #2 -**
Half of the sidebar navigation only shows up when the screen is not mobile/desktop. So somewhere in the Tablet category you only get half of the sidebar.

**Problem #3 -** Grids don't want to display 2 blocks in mobile view, instead it's only one block. As shown in Problem 1 image.

[image]

Here is the JSFiddle **https://jsfiddle.net/fdkdvr2b/1/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    htmlbodyHeightUpdate()
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        htmlbodyHeightUpdate()
    });
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        height2 = $('.main').height()
        htmlbodyHeightUpdate()
    });
```

^ Had to put above as Stackoverflow did not want to allow me to submit JSFiddle without code. But you will find all code in the JSFiddle. (css, html & js)

And here is embeded code where you can see results (fullscreen) **https://jsfiddle.net/fdkdvr2b/1/embedded/**

Comment: The code that you shared has no `padding-top:70px` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem #1: Place this rule inside a media query >

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 70px;
  }
}
```

Problem #2: I don't think you've explicitly declared a width for your sidebar. Declare a width and add `position: fixed` then offset the `main` div by the same about.

```
nav.sidebar {
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    right: -300px;
    height: 100%;
}
.main {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
```

Problem #3: You're declaring `col-xs-12` which takes up the entire container, use `col-xs-6` to include to columns.

Other items to note.
1) It may be best to include an additional column size for medium viewports other you'll probably have overflow.
2) On smaller screens (around 400px or less) you should consider **resizing** your logo because there isn't enough space for it and the `navbar-toggle`.
3) Your title, tags and langs (depending on how many items/length these can end being) may be better stacked one over the other because the thumbnails just don't have that much space to offer when the viewport is small/medium and you'll see these overflow from the thumbnail/column otherwise.

See working example Snippet at FullPage.

```js
function htmlbodyHeightUpdate() {
  var height3 = $(window).height()
  var height1 = $('.nav').height() + 50
  height2 = $('.main').height()
  if (height2 > height3) {
    $('html').height(Math.max(height1, height3, height2) + 10);
    $('body').height(Math.max(height1, height3, height2) + 10);
  } else {
    $('html').height(Math.max(height1, height3, height2));
    $('body').height(Math.max(height1, height3, height2));
  }

}
$(document).ready(function() {
  htmlbodyHeightUpdate()
  $(window).resize(function() {
    htmlbodyHeightUpdate()
  });
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    height2 = $('.main').height()
    htmlbodyHeightUpdate()
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);
 body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
nav.sidebar.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
nav.sidebar,
.main {
  -webkit-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
}
nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li a > i {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.navbar > .container .navbar-brand,
.navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #b11 url('https://e71a723b872a3a54921d-0feb5a410d64308aeb3d333fa1955229.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/assets.rev-1.sbf/bokkusu-logo-2016-v4.4.1.webp') no-repeat center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
}
.navbar-inverse {
  border: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-left: 300px;
  }
  nav.sidebar.navbar.sidebar > .container .navbar-brand,
  nav.sidebar.navbar.sidebar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  nav.sidebar .navbar-brand,
  nav.sidebar .navbar-header {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  nav.sidebar a {
    padding-right: 13px;
  }
  nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li {
    border-bottom: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) solid;
  }
  nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  /*allows nav box to use 100% width*/
  nav.sidebar .navbar-collapse,
  nav.sidebar .container-fluid {
    padding: 0;
  }
  /*colors dropdown box text */
  nav..navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #777;
  }
  /*gives sidebar width/height*/
  nav.sidebar {
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: -300px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  /*give sidebar 100% width;*/
  nav.sidebar li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /* Move nav to full on mouse over*/
  nav.sidebar:hover {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  /*for hiden things when navbar hidden*/
  .forAnimate {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  color: #CCC;
  background-color: transparent;
}
nav:hover .forAnimate {
  opacity: 1;
}
section {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 70px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 12.5px
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .navbar > .container .navbar-brand,
  .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    width: 240px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 8px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse sidebar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Latest <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-lg pull-right"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tags <i class="fa fa-tags fa-lg pull-right"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Artists <i class="fa fa-pencil-square fa-lg pull-right"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Groups <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg pull-right"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Random <i class="fa fa-repeat fa-lg pull-right"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum <i class="fa fa-life-ring fa-lg pull-right"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog <i class="fa fa-rss fa-lg pull-right"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="main">

  <div class="container-fluid browse-content-view">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 browse-view">
        <div class="thumbnail browse-view-thumb">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x450" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>title</h4>
            <p><span class="label label-primary">tage</span>
            </p>
            <p><span class="label label-default">langs</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 browse-view">
        <div class="thumbnail browse-view-thumb">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x450" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>title</h4>
            <p><span class="label label-primary">tage</span>
            </p>
            <p><span class="label label-default">langs</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 browse-view">
        <div class="thumbnail browse-view-thumb">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x450" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>title</h4>
            <p><span class="label label-primary">tage</span>
            </p>
            <p><span class="label label-default">langs</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 browse-view">
        <div class="thumbnail browse-view-thumb">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x450" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>title</h4>
            <p><span class="label label-primary">tage</span>
            </p>
            <p><span class="label label-default">langs</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 browse-view">
        <div class="thumbnail browse-view-thumb">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x450" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>title</h4>
            <p><span class="label label-primary">tage</span>
            </p>
            <p><span class="label label-default">langs</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 browse-view">
        <div class="thumbnail browse-view-thumb">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x450" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>title</h4>
            <p><span class="label label-primary">tage</span>
            </p>
            <p><span class="label label-default">langs</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 browse-view">
        <div class="thumbnail browse-view-thumb">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x450" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>title</h4>
            <p><span class="label label-primary">tage</span>
            </p>
            <p><span class="label label-default">langs</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 browse-view">
        <div class="thumbnail browse-view-thumb">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x450" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>title</h4>
            <p><span class="label label-primary">tage</span>
            </p>
            <p><span class="label label-default">langs</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-xs-6 browse-view">
        <div class="thumbnail browse-view-thumb">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x450" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4>title</h4>
            <p><span class="label label-primary">tage</span>
            </p>
            <p><span class="label label-default">langs</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```